# Change "None" to nothing ("") when the metric is Null

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am adding a metric to a view's page caption. When it's null, it's showing "Null" or "None". What I want is to not show anything when it's null. Is there a way to make it happen?

I am thinking to cast the metric to string so I can add "else ''" in the editor but didn't work. Any ideas?

[image: caption.]
I added these two metrics and want to show the green one when it's good and red one when it's bad. however as you can see in the caption, the red one is "Null" instead of showing nothing.

[image: the metric for good]
the metric for good

[image: the metric for bad]
the metric for bad

Comment: can you show screenshots of this and of the calculation leading to your value?

Comment: @Scinana added, thanks!

Comment: If you don’t like the behavior of the stock title, color legend etc, then make your own replacement as a worksheet — I.e. a worksheet with a text mark type to serve as a substitute title. A bit more effort but gives you more control

Answer (score 1):

From the way you have defined your calculations, only one of them will be true while the other one is false (ie. either your ARR Churn Rate... is higher or equal than 0 making the "good" calculation true, or your calculation will be lower than 0 making the "bad" calculation true).

If a calculation is false, then no value will be calculated for it, making it end up as null (while the other calculation will be true and will have a value).

Why don't you use a single calculation with 2 different result options (ie. IF.... condition THEN..."good" ELSE "bad") and assign colours based on the good/bad result?